# vuejs component template files

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, vue.js

I'm looking to build a simple SPA with Vue.js. I'd like to load different templates and animate a transition between them like this:

http://codepen.io/michaeljcalkins/pen/BNqREZ

The example is great, but I'd like to load each component's template from a separate file.

Something like:

```
var Foo = Vue.extend({
    template: '/foo.html'
```

I went through the documentation but I can't seem to find anything. How would I go about achieving something like this?

Thank you!

Comment: They wrote a blogpost explaining why vue does not have this: http://vuejs.org/2015/10/28/why-no-template-url/

Comment: Well, that explains why I couldn't figure out how to do it! Thanks for the resource, Björn. I will mark this as solved.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Björn above, it  doesn't look like it's possible to use Template URL's in Vue. Thanks Björn!